# How to write to csv file with StringBuilder ignoring the first row/line of CSV?

Tags: c#, csv, stringbuilder

Since the first row of this CSV file already includes the column names, so I just want to ignore the first line and start to write from second line with StringBuilder.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (DataRow dr in distinctValues.Rows)
            {
                vendor = dr.ItemArray[0].ToString();
                for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (vendor == ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["VendorCode"].ToString())
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                        {
                            if (j != 0)
                                sb.Append(",");
                            sb.Append(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][ds.Tables[0].Columns[j]]);
                        }
                        sb.AppendLine();
                    }
                }
                File.WriteAllText(@csvFile, sb.ToString());
            }
```

At last i understand that what i need is not to write a file but edit a file. so a changing of mind finally gives the answer.
**File.AppendAllText** is what i really need.

Comment: Show us what you have so far

Comment: What code do you currently have..? this is not a difficult task. have you tried googling on the internet for C# examples It sounds like you have not tried anything

Comment: @DJKRAZE i tried. but there are only solutions for reading a csv file not writing.

Comment: Are there lines after the first row containing the column names that you want to preserve?

Comment: I think you should write the file in append mode instead. Look into FileMode.Append.

Comment: @cameronjchurch only the first row has all the column names. other than that, it's a empty csv file.

Comment: There's also File.AppendText("pathtofile");

Comment: @A-Dubb thx my friend. actually i used File.AppendAllText to fix the problem.

Comment: Pretty sweet. Writing each line one at a time instead of all at once is always more efficient for larger files, but writing all at once via AppendAllText should get you by in most cases.

Comment: @A-Dubb yep, u r right since i only got quite a few lines to write in. but your tip is valuable when it deals with larger ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

[File.AppendText("pathtofile")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx)

or

`FileMode.Append` via `FileStream`

If the case of `File.AppendText`, all your calls to `sb.AppendLine()` would become `sw.WriteLine()` in the example below:

```
 // This text is always added, making the file longer over time 
 // if it is not deleted.

using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path)) 
{
    sw.WriteLine("This");
    sw.WriteLine("is Extra");
    sw.WriteLine("Text");
}
```

Comment: Dude, u r quick and smart.

Comment: Thanks bro. Anything I can do to help.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
class Program
{
    private const string csv ="Header\r\nLine1\r\nLine2";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(csv);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        bool header = true;
        while (true)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();

            if(header)
            {
                header = false;
                continue;
            }

            if (line == null)
                break;
            builder.AppendLine(line);

        }

        Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: If you actually like this answer, then it's probably simpler to just blindly call reader.ReadLine() and discard the result before starting your loop. That removes all the conditional logic within the body of the loop since you know you've already discarded the first row. Of course assumes that the header will ALWAYS be present in the file. Those sorts of invariants make life much simpler.